# iPhone-only app having UI issues on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm having an issue with my UI that I cannot find any solution to. I have pretty basic constraints/attributes on a UIButton and a few labels that work great on every size iPhone screen. For some reason, when I run the app on iPad the background color of my button is cleared and the sizing on my labels are off.

iPhone:

[image: iPhone]

iPhone 4:

[image: iPhone 4]

iPad:
[image: iPad]

Side-by-side in Preview:
[image: Preview]

edit:

File Inspector:
[image: File Inspector]

Comment: Try running your app in an iPhone 4 (ant 3.5" iPhone really) simulator. If you get it to work there, it should work on the iPad.

Comment: @rmaddy it works on iPhone 4, I'll update with screenshot.

Comment: @jmalatras have you preview your storyboard design side by side?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes, just edited in screenshot of that.

Comment: @jmalatras is your storyboard ViewController using `size classes` or iPhone only?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `Size Classes` for your ViewController in your `Storyboard` as shown below:

[image]

However, if the problem still persists, consider making two storyboards. One for iPhone and one for iPad. Follow these steps:

1. Go to `File > New > Files...` and create a new empty storyboard.

[image]

2. Disable `Size Classes` for this storyboard and choose `iPad`.

[image]

3. Link your ViewController.

[image]

4. Set as initial view and see the arrow on the left.

[image]

5. Give the two storyboards different names.

[image]

6. Finally, go to your `info.plist`, get rid of the original `Main storyboard file base name` property, and add a new one for iPhone and iPad each.

[image]

Now you can edit iPhone and iPad storyboards separately like before when using the older version of Xcode.

Tell me how it goes. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I don't seem to have the option for Size Classes in the file inspector? I believe I'm using the latest version of Xcode/Swift. Is there something I'm missing? Added screenshot to original question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I wasn't using the latest version of Xcode. Perhaps `Use Trait Variations` is equivalent to `Use Size Classes`. While using separate storyboards might be more simple when making small apps, you can try dealing with the auto layout problem following the tutorial [here](https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/).

Comment: It appears that is equivalent, however it didn't fix the issue unfortunately. I didn't have an iPhone 4s simulator installed by default and used the above screenshot from the preview screen. I managed to install a 4s simulator and am getting the same issue with the button when I run it on there. I've experimented with different constrains and haven't been able to figure it out.